# How to find value exist in two dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

In my project I have array and when I echo it using `pre` tag it display like this.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => 1,31
        [hour] => 0-5
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 adjkerntz -a
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => 1
        [hour] => 3
        [mday] => 1
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.update_bogons.sh
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => */60
        [hour] => *
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 /usr/local/sbin/expiretable -v -t 3600 sshlockout
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => */60
        [hour] => *
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 /usr/local/sbin/expiretable -v -t 3600 webConfiguratorlockout
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => 1
        [hour] => 1
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.dyndns.update
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => */60
        [hour] => *
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 /usr/local/sbin/expiretable -v -t 3600 virusprot
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => 30
        [hour] => 12
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.update_urltables
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minute] => */1
        [hour] => *
        [mday] => *
        [month] => *
        [wday] => *
        [who] => root
        [command] => /usr/local/www/checksum.php
    )

)
```

Now I want to check if **command=/usr/local/www/checksum.php** is exist or not. so, I made this code

```
if (!in_array('/usr/local/www/checksum.php', $array['command'])) {
    echo 'not';
}
else{
    echo 'yes';
}
```

But it always echo not...and warning displayed like **Message: Undefined index: command**. I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Because it's `stdClass Object` so you need access the value like this  `$row->command`

Answer (score 0):

Your array is found inside an object, so you must access the object and *then* the array.

You can do something like this,

```
if (!in_array('/usr/local/www/checksum.php', $arr[0]->obj['command'])) {
    echo 'not';
}else{
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Note, the `[0]` in this case means the first object inside your array, so you are trying to check if `command` exists in all of your arrays, you will have to iterate through them like this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $obj){

    var_dump(in_array('/usr/local/www/checksum.php', $obj[$key]['command'])); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array and check the value while you have multidimensional array

```
$new_array=array();
foreach ($array as $row){
if($row['command']=="/usr/local/www/checksum.php"){
$new_array[] =$row;
}
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array you are using is 2-dimensional array. You can not use this code..

```
if (!in_array('/usr/local/www/checksum.php', $array['command'])) {
    echo 'not';
}
else{
    echo 'yes';
}
```

because it does not contain the key like `[command]` .

first break in single dimension(normal array) per element then check. here is the code. Use object method

```
$result = 'not';
foreach($array as $array_element) {
    if (strstr($array_element->command, '/usr/local/www/checksum.php')) {
        $result = 'yes';
        break;
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's `stdClass Object` so you need to access the value like this  `$row->command`

```
foreach ($array as $row){

   if($row->command=="/usr/local/www/checksum.php")
   {
         echo 'yes';
         break;
   }

}
```